# How do I know if requestLocationUpdate is active?

Tags: android

I would like to set some property only if `requestLocationUpdate()` is actually running. How do I test if it is "on"?

Comment: It's "on" until you call `removeUpdates()` to stop it. If you receive a callback or intent about the location provider being disabled (e.g., `onProviderDisabled()`, `onStatusChanged()`, or `KEY_STATUS_CHANGED` intent), it's "paused" temporarily until the provider is enabled again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the interval in which the `requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES, MIN_DIST_BTW_UPDATES, listener);` according to your requirements by setting the minimum time and distance covering which, will cause the updates to function again.

This repeatedly sends updates using the specified parameters to the LocationListener until you call `removeUpdates()`. If you set the values to 0 then there will be no delay between updates.

If you want to actually go on and "test" if it's **on** just get the location into an object and see if its null.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple flag for it.

after calling `requestLocationUpdate()`, just add a flag, for example `boolean locate = true;`

and after calling `removeUpdates()` reset the flag to `false`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I'm getting the signal cutoff at some points, and then have to start the app again by hand.

Comment: Would you care to explain more and I'll try to help?